# Parse the JSON in spring?

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I know it is a simple question .But I can't find a answer.

How to parse this `Jquery ajax`.

My `Jquery ajax` `success` response will be,

`{"status" : "ready"};`

Help me to do this.

Comment: You need to use a JSON library like GSON , Jackson .

Comment: Have you tried anything here? With Jackson, that will be `ObjectMapper`'s `.readTree()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*My Jquery ajax success response will be,*

From the above line , I assume you are looking to parse the JSON response in the client side. In javascript you can parse it as :

```
var json = '{"status" : "ready"};',    
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
```

In Java , using [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) :

```
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonElement element = parser.parse(yourJsonString); 
JsonObject jsonObject = element.getAsJsonObject();
```